Impossible to send messages to Topic
I'm trying to use the the documentation of Hedera in order to send message to a private topic.
I followed every steps and I don't understand why the simple code of the documentation doesn't work for me. I'm a beginner so I suppose my mistake is pretty simple but I will really appreciate some help !
PS : I created a testnet account and my .env file is correct.
[Running] node "/Users/cl/Documents/VSCODE/Blockchain_HCS/hello-hedera-js-sdk/query_ledger.js"
/Users/cl/Documents/VSCODE/Blockchain_HCS/hello-hedera-js-sdk/node_modules/@hashgraph/sdk/lib/Executable.cjs:675
    throw new Error(`max attempts of ${maxAttempts.toString()} was reached for request with last error being: ${persistentError != null ? persistentError.toString() : ""}`);
          ^

Error: max attempts of 10 was reached for request with last error being: GrpcServiceError: gRPC service failed with status: TIMEOUT
    at TopicCreateTransaction.execute (/Users/cl/Documents/VSCODE/Blockchain_HCS/hello-hedera-js-sdk/node_modules/@hashgraph/sdk/lib/Executable.cjs:675:11)
    at async submitFirstMessage (/Users/cl/Documents/VSCODE/Blockchain_HCS/hello-hedera-js-sdk/query_ledger.js:24:20)

Node.js v21.7.1

[Done] exited with code=1 in 100.343 seconds

Code of the documentation :
console.clear();
require("dotenv").config();
const {
  AccountId,
  PrivateKey,
  Client,
  TopicCreateTransaction,
  TopicMessageQuery,
  TopicMessageSubmitTransaction,
} = require("@hashgraph/sdk");

// Grab the OPERATOR_ID and OPERATOR_KEY from the .env file
const myAccountId = process.env.MY_ACCOUNT_ID;
const myPrivateKey = process.env.MY_PRIVATE_KEY;

// Build Hedera testnet and mirror node client
const client = Client.forTestnet();

// Set the operator account ID and operator private key
client.setOperator(myAccountId, myPrivateKey);

async function submitFirstMessage() {
  // Create a new topic
  let txResponse = await new TopicCreateTransaction().execute(client);

  // Grab the newly generated topic ID
  let receipt = await txResponse.getReceipt(client);
  let topicId = receipt.topicId;
  console.log(`Your topic ID is: ${topicId}`);

  // Wait 5 seconds between consensus topic creation and subscription creation
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

  // Create the topic
  new TopicMessageQuery()
    .setTopicId(topicId)
    .subscribe(client, null, (message) => {
      let messageAsString = Buffer.from(message.contents, "utf8").toString();
      console.log(
        `${message.consensusTimestamp.toDate()} Received: ${messageAsString}`
      );
    });

  // Send message to topic
  let sendResponse = await new TopicMessageSubmitTransaction({
    topicId: topicId,
    message: "Hello, HCS!",
  }).execute(client);
  const getReceipt = await sendResponse.getReceipt(client);

  // Get the status of the transaction
  const transactionStatus = getReceipt.status;
  console.log("The message transaction status: " + transactionStatus.toString());
}

submitFirstMessage();

I looked at the official documentation + the official tutorial of Hedera.

What Hedera SDK version are you using? Usually upgrading to the latest version resolves gRPC issues.

@sbrajchuk I'm using the last version. Now my only issue is this one when I'm trying the official JS code for a private topic : Your topic ID is: (..)
/hello-hedera-js-sdk/node_modules/@hashgraph/sdk/lib/transaction/Transaction.cjs:617
const publicKeyData = publicKey.toBytesRaw();
^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBytesRaw')
at TopicMessageSubmitTransaction.signWith (/hello-hedera-js-sdk/node_modules/@hashgraph/sdk/lib/transaction/Transaction.cjs:617:37)

I would say there is a problem with private key.

@Clément  This code creates a public topic (not a private one)let txResponse = await new TopicCreateTransaction().execute(client);. If you wish to have a private topic, you will need to include a submit key. e.g. let txResponse = await new TopicCreateTransaction().setSubmitKey(aPublicKey).execute(client);

@Clément FYI I have created an example of a private HCS topic where only 5 accounts are allowed to write to it (and anyone can read from it) - LMK if you are able to get this to work: https://github.com/hedera-dev/hedera-code-snippets/blob/5e201f56/hcs-topic-permissioned-write/hcs-write.js#L49-L63
